# Accessing Thumbdrive firmware

Tags: usb-flash-drive, firmware

I have a few questions about USB drive firmware:

**How can I access a thumbdrive's firmware?**

**Is it possible to avoid running a thumbdrive's firmware when plugging it in, and instead strip a full iso image from the drive?**

**Also (and perhaps this is excessively hopeful), is there any one basic free application that can restore to factory default the firmware of any thumbdrive?**

Some modern malware has been designed to affects the firmware of USB drives, and to be able to access/inspect/restore thumbdrive firmware would be helpful if I ever ended up in the situation.

And I'd assume that accessing the firmware (programmatically if nothing else) is possible at least for some devices, since [hackers are now able to do it](http://arstechnica.com/security/2014/07/this-thumbdrive-hacks-computers-badusb-exploit-makes-devices-turn-evil/) ([here's another example](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2460540/most-usb-thumb-drives-can-be-reprogrammed-to-silently-infect-computers.html)).

Comment: There is no universal method to achieve this. Indeed, there are various standards, but no guarantee if a device implements one.

Comment: You might want to watch the presentation if you haven't already.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nuruzFqMgIw

Answer (score 1):

> How can I access a thumbdrive's firmware?

It completely depends on the specific hardware.  There is no generic method that applies to all devices.  For some devices you would have to crack open a case.  Some devices have a method to update firmware via software specific to the device.

> Is it possible to avoid running a thumbdrive's firmware when plugging it in

No it is physically stored on the USB drive and executed by the processor on the USB device as soon as it is connected to power.  Short of hardware hacking you cannot stop it.

> Also (and perhaps this is excessively hopeful), is there any one basic free application that can restore to factory default the firmware of any thumbdrive?

It simply doesn't exist yet, and there would be no magical vendor neutral way to do this.  Different types of hardware need different firmware.  Vendors would/will? need to start hosting their firmware to be downloaded.  Devices that don't have an official way to update firmware might not be fixable.